# How to change tag dynamically in hyperHTML

Tags: javascript, hyperhtml

This code does not work.

```
const render = ({title, tag, values}) => {
    bind(document.body)`
        <h1>${title}</h1>
        <div>
            <${tag} data=${values}></${tag}>
        </div>
    `
}

render({title: "test", tag: "custom-elem1", values: {foo: "bar"}})
```

Can I change tag dynamically using hyperHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not like the answer but it's **nope**, you can't.

The reason is that *hyperHTML*, like any other similar library, doesn't work with strings, it works with DOM, and in the DOM world you cannot change a tag name, even if you try.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.tagName = 'P';
console.log(div.tagName); // "DIV"
```

What you could do instead, is to return the element you like.

```
const render = ({title, tag, values}) => {
  const ref = document.body;
  bind(ref)`
    <h1>${title}</h1>
    <div>${(() => {
      switch tag:
        case 'custom-elem1':
          return wire(ref)`<custom-elem1 data=${values} />`;
        case 'custom-elem2':
          return wire(ref)`<custom-elem2 data=${values} />`;
        case 'custom-elem3':
          return wire(ref)`<custom-elem3 data=${values} />`;
      })()
    }</div>`;
};
```

In that case, you can do whatever you want, as long as you won't try to change DOM tags nature on the fly, 'cause not even *hyperHTML* can do that

Comment: In my case, it is difficult to enumerate all possible tags. I will try direct DOM operation partly. Thank you.